# How can I add to an AJAX array result

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an AJAX request where I want to add more properties to the returned AJAX result. Any help would be great

Here is my AJAX request code:

```
var form_data = {};

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../../../sample_data/chart1.json",
    data: form_data,

    success: function( response) {
        var result = $(data);
        console.log(result.datasets.push(style)); 
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart_div_won").getContext("2d");
        var options = {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            pointDotRadius: 5,                                                  
            showXLabels: 5,
        };

        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(response, options);


    },
    error: function() {
        $('div#chart-container').html('<div class="notification-body"><p class="notification-heading">Loading error...</p><p class="notification-description">Unfortunatley for some reason visual data failed to load.</p></div>'); 
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
});
```

Which returns the following data:

```
{  
  "labels":[  
     "1 Feb",      
     "8 Feb",      
     "15 Feb",      
     "22 Feb",      
     "29 Feb",      
     "7 Mar",      
     "14 Mar",      
     "21 Mar",      
     "28 Mar",      
     "4 Apr",      
     "11 Apr",      
     "18 Apr",      
     "25 Apr"
  ],
  "datasets":[  
     {  

        "data":[  
           77,
           55,
           40,
           65,
           59,
           80,
           81,
           56,
           55,
           65,
           59,
           80,
           75            
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

My question is I want to add/push into the returned 'datasets' array the following (at 'data:' level):

```
fillColor:"rgba(253,0,20,0.2)",
strokeColor:"rgba(253,0,20,1)",
pointColor:"#fff",
pointStrokeColor:"rgba(253,0,20,1)",
pointHighlightFill:"#fff",
pointHighlightStroke:"rgba(253,0,20,1)"
```

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Loop over the `datasets` array and use `$.extend` to merge your object with each of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned data becomes a regular Javascript object. You can add properties to the desired level with regular assignments:

```
res.datasets[0].fillColor = "rgba(253,0,20,0.2)";
res.datasets[0].strokeColor = "rgba(253,0,20,1)";
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You have nested arrays. So you need to do something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.datasets.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < result.datasets[i].data.length; j++)
    {
        result.datasets[i].data[j]["fillColor"] = "rgba(253,0,20,0.2)";
        result.datasets[i].data[j]["strokeColor"] = "rgba(253,0,20,1)";
        result.datasets[i].data[j]["pointColor"] = "#fff";
        result.datasets[i].data[j]["pointStrokeColor"] = "rgba(253,0,20,1)";
        result.datasets[i].data[j]["pointHighlightFill"] = "#fff";
        result.datasets[i].data[j]["pointHighlightStroke"] = "rgba(253,0,20,1)";
    }
}
```